# What's the relation between Map output records & Reduce input records

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop2

I have this hadoop program:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;

public class Question1_1 {

    public static class WordCountMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            for (String word : value.toString().split("\\s+")) {
                context.write(new Text(word), new IntWritable(1));
            }
        }
    }

    public static class WordCountReducer extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {
        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "Question1_1");


        job.setJarByClass(Question1_1.class);
        job.setMapperClass(WordCountMapper.class);    
        job.setReducerClass(WordCountReducer.class);

        // Types of Key/Value
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        // Input & Output Files
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));


        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);

    }

}
```

I run this program against a txt file. I got this in the logs:

```
    15:09:11 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: session.id is deprecated. Instead, use dfs.metrics.session-id
15:09:12 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
15:09:12 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
15:09:12 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
15:09:12 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.outputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.outputformat.class
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.combine.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.combine.class
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.mapoutput.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.value.class
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.mapoutput.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.key.class
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.reduce.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduces
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
15:09:12 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_local958404083_0001
15:09:12 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-hamza/mapred/staging/hamza958404083/.staging/job_local958404083_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
15:09:12 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-hamza/mapred/staging/hamza958404083/.staging/job_local958404083_0001/job.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
15:09:12 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-hamza/mapred/local/localRunner/hamza/job_local958404083_0001/job_local958404083_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.retry.interval;  Ignoring.
15:09:12 WARN conf.Configuration: file:/tmp/hadoop-hamza/mapred/local/localRunner/hamza/job_local958404083_0001/job_local958404083_0001.xml:an attempt to override final parameter: mapreduce.job.end-notification.max.attempts;  Ignoring.
15:09:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8080/
15:09:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_local958404083_0001
15:09:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter set in config null
15:09:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: OutputCommitter is org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter
15:09:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Waiting for map tasks
15:09:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Starting task: attempt_local958404083_0001_m_000000_0
15:09:12 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: Processing split: file:/home/hamza/workspace/TPIntroHadoop/flickrSample.txt:0+53568
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
15:09:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: Spilling map output
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufend = 62647; bufvoid = 104857600
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396(104857584); kvend = 26205172(104820688); length = 9225/6553600
15:09:12 INFO mapred.MapTask: Finished spill 0
15:09:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local958404083_0001_m_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
15:09:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: map
15:09:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local958404083_0001_m_000000_0' done.
15:09:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Finishing task: attempt_local958404083_0001_m_000000_0
15:09:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
15:09:12 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorProcessTree : [ ]
15:09:12 INFO mapred.Merger: Merging 1 sorted segments
15:09:12 INFO mapred.Merger: Down to the last merge-pass, with 1 segments left of total size: 41944 bytes
15:09:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
15:09:12 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.skip.on is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.skiprecords
15:09:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task:attempt_local958404083_0001_r_000000_0 is done. And is in the process of committing
15:09:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: 
15:09:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task attempt_local958404083_0001_r_000000_0 is allowed to commit now
15:09:12 INFO output.FileOutputCommitter: Saved output of task 'attempt_local958404083_0001_r_000000_0' to file:/home/hamza/workspace/TPIntroHadoop/sresult/_temporary/0/task_local958404083_0001_r_000000
15:09:12 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: reduce > reduce
15:09:12 INFO mapred.Task: Task 'attempt_local958404083_0001_r_000000_0' done.
15:09:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local958404083_0001 running in uber mode : false
15:09:13 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
15:09:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local958404083_0001 completed successfully
15:09:13 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 27
    File System Counters
        FILE: Number of bytes read=149581
        FILE: Number of bytes written=496089
        FILE: Number of read operations=0
        FILE: Number of large read operations=0
        FILE: Number of write operations=0
    Map-Reduce Framework
        Map input records=100
        Map output records=2307
        Map output bytes=62647
        Map output materialized bytes=42089
        Input split bytes=122
        Combine input records=2307
        Combine output records=1218
        Reduce input groups=1218
        Reduce shuffle bytes=0
        Reduce input records=1218
        Reduce output records=1218
        Spilled Records=2436
        Shuffled Maps =0
        Failed Shuffles=0
        Merged Map outputs=0
        GC time elapsed (ms)=0
        CPU time spent (ms)=0
        Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=0
        Total committed heap usage (bytes)=460324864
    File Input Format Counters 
        Bytes Read=53568
    File Output Format Counters 
        Bytes Written=37479
```

**Question:** What's the relation between Map output records & Reduce input records? What does Reduce input groups represent?

Comment: I think the combiner combines some of the Map outputs (changing them from 2307 to 1218. Then it is going to the reduce phase. There is no strict relationship - it depends on the input. Basically the combiner combines map values  - check this out https://www.tutorialspoint.com/map_reduce/map_reduce_combiners.htm

Comment: Your Mapper and Reducer are doing nothing... So, what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

In the mapper, you use `context.write(key, value)`

In the reducer, all values for a particular `key` from the mapper are combined into the `Iterable<?> values`

To get something to be written to `new Path(output)`, you need to use the `context` again from the reducer

Answer (score 0):

So you have the following counters:

```
Map input records=100
Map output records=2307
Combine input records=2307
Combine output records=1218
Reduce input groups=1218
Reduce input records=1218
Reduce output records=1218
```

From this you can make some determinations about the data you're processing:

1. Your `mapper` has read `100` records of input and produced `2307` key/value output records. This tells you how much you're expanding the data.
2. You have a combiner (your reducer in this case) which has taken in `2307` and locally reduced this from `2307` to `1218`. Effectively, because you have only one input split (this 1 mapper) your reducer shouldnt have any futher effect.
3. The combiner outputs `1218` records which matches the number of input records to the reducer.
4. The reducer receives `1218` records, and because the data is fully reduced at this point, it also tells you that there are `1218` groups. A group is effectively the count of keys. Normally you can use `group` and `record` counts to determine how the key you're using relates to the number of values they have. In this case you saw the combiner reduce the data by about 50%, so you could say you have about 2 values per key.
5. The data is fully reduced, so the reducer doesn't need to do much work since each key has one value at this point, so it just outputs `1218` records.

In my experience, once you are running on a larger dataset and have may mappers running, the combiner counts become less meaningfull. They can read and write the same data multiple times, so you effectively look at what the mapper output and the reducers input. But in this case you can see whats happening.

Comment: Can you post the link of the docs where talks about this? Thanks